# What have i done wrong in using blastn to get this error?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, miniconda

I am havingtrouble figuring out why i get this error:

blastn -db unassigner_species.fasta -outfmt 6 -query sample1.fasta -out sample1_out.txt
Command line argument error: Argument "out". File is not accessible:

I am using ubuntu, miniconda

I may have changed some wsl permisionss, but i do not know how to get them back to normal nor do i remeber what i did. I have restarted my computer but still get the same error.